# Typeset an author without affiliation with authblk

Tags: titles, authblk

I'm currently using [authblk](http://ctan.org/pkg/authblk) to typeset authors and corresponding affiliation(s) in a proceeding article, one of the authors has no affiliation.

Commands are the following:

```
\author[*]{Name1}
\author[**]{Name2}
\author{Name3}

\affil[*]{Dept #1}
\affil[**]{Dept #1}
```

However, the package does not recognize that `Name3` has no affiliation, and it's typeset like it's affiliated with `Dept #1`.

How should I modify the autlblk package to overcome this?

Comment: Make a blank affiliation and assign it to Name3?

Comment: No, because it will produce an unwanted superscript...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just put a single space as the marker for author 3 (you need the space, not just `[]`).

```
\author[ ]{Name3}
```

Comment: You'll want to add a \hspace{-1ex} after the space in order to get rid of the space between the author name and, if applicable, the following comma.

Comment: As a possible improvement, with UTF-aware latex you can use a zero width space character to avoid possible problems with overshooting the negative hspace. Grab one here: http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/200B.html

Answer (score 0):

I find a single way.

```
\author[1]{name 1}
\author[2]{name 2}

\affil[1]{...}
\affil[2]{...}
```

In the output, if you do not like the upper script in the affiliation, you add
`\affil[**]{...}`
where I use `*` to present the space. 
I notice that one space is not enough, you need at least two space.
In my case, I use
`\affil[  ]{Email:**@**}`
then the upper script disappeared.

Comment: Welcome, which part of the question does this answer? I am a bit confused.

Comment: Likewise, I'm a little confused about what ends up happening. Would you be able to post a screenshot of the output?